# Transfer data and configuration to new server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

I have Server with Windows 2008 SP2 and would like to upgrade it to Windows 2008 R2. The problem is that many configurations was done on current server like MSSQL and IIS7 and reconfigure everything on new server will takes several days. I am new to server administration and maybe someone could suggest easy way to backup all data and restore on new server. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Do the upgrade to R2 on the existing server
2. Back it up
3. Restore it to the new hardware

Comment: +1 But might I suggest a "0. Back it up" before the upgrade?

Comment: @Jscott - of course, I had assumed anyone would do that. He says he's new, so maybe he wouldn't think of that. Tomas - best practice is to never perform a change unless you have a good backout plan.

Comment: Be aware, the only way this can legally work (and possibly technically due to activation issues) is if you obtain a 2008 R2 Full Retail copy OR a volume license.  You cannot upgrade using OEM media and you cannot transfer the license of the 2008 system (by "upgrading" with a retail or VL license, the new license is what would apply and transferring to new hardware should be permissible then).

Comment: That said, though it may take time to reconfigure, you're more likely to have a long term success if you do NOT upgrade.  Further, if your 2008 server is x86 (32 bit), then you CANNOT upgrade as 2008 R2 is 64 bit and there are no cross architecture upgrade paths.